# HAML: form_tag dilemma (indentation?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I'm making "user settings form", and stuck with HAML:

```
= form_tag('/')
  - [1,2,3].each do |i|
    =  check_box_tag "accept#{i}"
  = submit_tag
```

This results in  "syntax error, unexpected kENSURE, expecting $end".

The working variant is

```
= form_tag('/')
  - [1,2,3].each do |i|
  =  check_box_tag "accept#{i}"
  = submit_tag
```

Results in

```
 <input id="accept1" name="accept1" type="checkbox" value="1" />
    <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Save changes" />
    <input id="accept2" name="accept2" type="checkbox" value="1" />
    <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Save changes" />
    <input id="accept3" name="accept3" type="checkbox" value="1" />
    <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Save changes" />
    <form action="/" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="tuniieYp9hgvGBMaYDjK2l3Mgjpxo9F1LPzqEF4ykHg=" /></div>
```

Wrong: controls outside form tag, 3 times submit button.

Any ideas on fixing would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Please edit for proper working variant display.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You should be passing a block to form_tag.  I think you want:

Rails 2.x:

```
- form_tag('/') do
  - [1, 2, 3].each do |i|
    = check_box_tag "accept#{i}"
  = submit_tag
```

Rails 3+:

```
= form_tag('/') do
  - [1, 2, 3].each do |i|
    = check_box_tag "accept#{i}"
  = submit_tag
```

Comment: this answer wont work for me. You should use = so the form will be actually printed out `= form_tag('/') do`

Comment: I believe that was a change in Rails 3 (?).  The answer is over 3 years old and predates Rails 3.