# How to get a search form to actually perform a search query (in Rails)

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, search, ruby-on-rails-4, haml

I have a search form that I created from [this tutorial](http://speckyboy.com/2012/02/15/how-to-build-a-stylish-css3-search-box/). But how do I get it to perform an actual query for a specified controller and a specified action?

```
%form
  %input{:placeholder => "Find something...", :required => "", :type => "text"}
    %button{:type => "submit"} Search
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a target for the form:

```
%form{ :action => "/rotas", :method => "get" }
  %input{:placeholder => "Find something...", :required => "", :type => "text"}
    %button{:type => "submit"} Search
```

Or you could use [form_tag helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag) , something like:

```
=form_tag(controller: :posts , action: :index, method: :get) do |f|
  = f.text_field :query, nil, :placeholder => "Find something..."
    = f.submit "Search"
```

and remember to watch out for [indentations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483592/haml-form-tag-problem-indentation) !

Comment: Thanks @Nimir, I can see that the first suggestion worked without messing up the styling. But how do I get the search text into the query? When I submit it, it only goes to `Started POST "/rotas" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-05 16:33:13 +0200`.

Comment: `/rotas` is an example, you should replace it with the path you want to receive the search query

Comment: Yes, I get that, but suppose I had the `/rotas` path, I would still need my query to be in the params. Like e.g. `/rotas?query=mysearch`.

Comment: @JohnSmith1976 perhaps you should go through http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html it includes the exact example of building a search form

Comment: @JohnSmith1976 try using `:method => "get" `

Comment: But unless I am missing something, your suggestion does not actually perform a search, right?

Comment: I does not seem like `:method => "get"` helps.

Comment: I am not sure i am following but the code i posted will submit a form to a rails controller were you should have an action that takes the query, probably calls a model method that do the activerecord query and returns the results back to the controller action which should render a view that displays it. All this is pretty well explained step by step in the link above

Comment: But the value from the input field should of course be in the query. Otherwise the search functionality can not be used to search for stuff.

Comment: @JohnSmith1976 ok, i have updated the answer (second example)

Comment: In the updated answer, `f` does not refer to anything.